# How to calculate the sum of the datatable column in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, datatable

I have a DataTable which has 5 columns:

- ID
- Name
- Account Number
- Branch
- Amount

The DataTable contains 5 rows.

How can I show the sum of the Amount Column in a Label Control as "Total Amount"?

Comment: Do you have the ADO.Net DataTable or by DataTable you mean the database table?

Comment: Is the data table just being used to supply the Total or is it being bound to another control, such as a gridView or repeater? Of you are purely extracting the total use Jonathan Woods suggestions below.

Comment: Do you know you have 5 rows, or could it be more or less?

Comment: thank you all for your effects. I got the answer.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To calculate the sum of a column in a DataTable use the [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method.

Example of usage from the linked MSDN article:

```
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["YourTableName"];

// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Amount)", string.Empty);
```

Display the result in your Total Amount Label like so:

```
lblTotalAmount.Text = sumObject.ToString();
```

Comment: He don't want filteration expression, he just want to calculate all rows amount. In your answer, Filteration expression means, it will compute sum where EmpId = 5.

Comment: It asks for filter. I dont have any conditions to filter. I want to sum  all the rows in the datatable.

Comment: Jay Thanks for the solution. It reduces my number of line code.

Answer (score 39):

```
 this.LabelControl.Text = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount"))
    .ToString();
```

If you want to filter the results:

```
 this.LabelControl.Text = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(y => y.Field<string>("SomeCol") != "foo")
    .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("MyColumn") )
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do like..

```
DataRow[] dr = dtbl.Select("SUM(Amount)");
txtTotalAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a ADO.Net DataTable you could do

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
   sum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Amount"]);
}
```

If you want to query the database table, you could use

```
Select Sum(Amount) From DataTable
```

Answer (score 6):

Compute Sum of Column in Datatable , Works 100%

```
lbl_TotaAmt.Text = MyDataTable.Compute("Sum(BalAmt)", "").ToString();
```

if you want to have any conditions, use it like this

```
   lbl_TotaAmt.Text = MyDataTable.Compute("Sum(BalAmt)", "srno=1 or srno in(1,2)").ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  public decimal Total()
    {
      decimal decTotal=(datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable).Compute("Sum(FieldName)","");
      return decTotal;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use Linq by Name Grouping

```
  var allEntries = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select r["Amount"];
```

using name space `using System.Linq;`

You can find the sample total,subtotal,grand total in datatable using c# at [Myblog](http://kuttyrajesh.blogspot.in/2016/02/sub-total-grand-total-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     dynamic value = dr[index].ToString();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     { 
         sum += Convert.ToInt32(value);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves

```
using System.Linq;


(datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable().Sum(c => c.Field<double>("valor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do this within your cshtml file, you can write it like this (including a LAMBDA expression):

```
<td><b>£@Model.Sum(i => i.Amount)</b></td>
```

You can remove the html tags, I just left them in to try and help with the example.