# Perform Aggregate function of DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net

I have to perform the aggregate function on the DataTable like Datatable.Compute but compute return the object i want to perform the aggregate function on the datatable and get the datarow .

```
_summaryTable.Compute("min(FareAdult)", whereClause 
                        + "AirlineDisplayName='" 
                        + Convert.ToString(airline["AirlineDisplayName"]) 
                        + "' and ( Stops=0) ");
```

but above code will only return the **min(FareAdult)** but i want to select the two column based on the above condition from datatable.

How can i do it through Linq
I have to select **min(FareAdult)** and the **TotelPrice** value of same row

Answer (score 0):

use `Select` instead `compute`

```
_summaryTable.Select("FilterationExpression");

DataRow[] dr = _summaryTable.Select("min(FareAdult),AirlineDisplayName='" + Convert.ToString(airline["AirlineDisplayName"]) + "' and ( Stops=0) ");
```

Comment: I have to select the Minimum  FareAdult

Comment: check this, and you will see you can add aggregate function as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892993/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net/5893078#5893078

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ method. This is pseudocode since I don't know the typing of your row, and I haven't been able to test it, but the idea is the same. Use LINQ to select the rows that match your criteria, order by the FareAdult and then select the first (minimum).

```
var minResult = (from row in _summaryTable.Rows
                where row.AirlineDisplayName == airline["AirlineDisplayName"] && row.Stops == 0
                orderby row.FareAdult
                select row).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CalcColumns()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable ();

    //enter code here

    // Create the first column.
    DataColumn priceColumn = new DataColumn();
    priceColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    priceColumn.ColumnName = "price";
    priceColumn.DefaultValue = 50;

    // Create the second, calculated, column.
    DataColumn taxColumn = new DataColumn();
    taxColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    taxColumn.ColumnName = "tax";
    taxColumn.Expression = "price * 0.0862";

    // Create third column.
    DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
    totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    totalColumn.ColumnName = "total";
    totalColumn.Expression = "price + tax";

    // Add columns to DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add(priceColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(taxColumn);
    table.Columns.Add(totalColumn);

    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    dataGrid1.DataSource = view;
}
```