# Get SUM of DataTable column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net

I have following values in DataTable

```
Affiliate Name | Call
---------------|-----
A              |   2
B              |   1  
B              |   0
A              |   3
```

How can I retrieve Total Count of `Call` against `Affiliate Name` 'A'. In example above, it should return 5.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string CallsOffered = //Get count
}
```

Comment: var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("Affiliate Name") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Affiliate Name = g.Key,
                      Count = g.Count(),
                      Call= g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Call"))
                  };

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the sum of the datatable column in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892993/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Daniel Its not a simple SUM.The sum of `Call` is dependent on the value of another column

Comment: @Daniel - this question about Sum of grouping result, result must return collection of sums

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DataTable.Compute` method

```
var sumOfA = dt.Compute("Sum(Call)", "[Affiliate Name] = 'A'");
```

Or use LINQ

```
var sumOfA = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Affiliate Name").Equals("A"))
               .Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("Call"));
```

In case you want get sum of calls for all values of `Affiliate Name` use LINQ with anonymous type

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("Affiliate Name"))
                .Select((group, dr) => new 
                {
                    AffiliateName = group.Key,
                   CallsCount = group.Sum(dr.Field<int>("Call")))
                });

foreach(var result in results)
{
    // Use results
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.AffiliateName}: {result.CallsCount}");
}
```

Comment: I will prefer LINQ. Thanks :)

Comment: not that it matters much but you forgot a quote in the end of the Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    int CallsOffered=0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      if(row["Affiliate_Name"].ToString()=="A")
        CallsOffered += int.Parse(row["Call"].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
object sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Call)", "Affiliate_Name = 'A'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// with this code you can use linq features in all other steps
// add each column you need them to use them with linq  
var records = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
new
{
    Affiliate = row.Field<string>("Affiliate(col name)"),
    Call = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<int>("Call(col name)"))
});
int count = records.Where(q => q.Affiliate == "A").Sum(q => q.Call);
```