# How to group by tables in datatable and sum them using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am a newbie here and I have an issue: I have 5 tables in my database with the same columns and headers, so I want to group by all the tables and and I want to sum them.

Suppose if there is a column `Amount` which is present in all 5 tables, then I want to group by the `Amount` and I want to sum all the 5 table values using Entity Framework.

This is my code which I'm using to do group by, but I'm unable to do the sum:

```
private DataTable ProcessData(DataSet ds)
{           
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["Name"], Col2 = r["Amt"], Col3 = r["Net"], Col4 = r["Data"] })
           .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["max"]).First())
           .CopyToDataTable();

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try object `Object sum=dt.Compute("Sum(Amt)", "");`

[How to calculate the sum of the datatable column in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892993/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net)